# Why does `recv()` of the connection from python multiprocessing block?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process

def f(conn):
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1, c2 = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(c1,))
    p.start()

    print(111)
    c2.send(123)
    print(222)
    print(c2.poll(5))
    print(333)
    c2.recv()
    print(444)

    p.join()
```

And the code blocks in `c2.recv()`. According to the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects):

> recv()
>
> Return an object sent from the other end of the connection using send(). Blocks until there is something to receive. Raises EOFError if there is nothing left to receive and the other end was closed.

But my code do not raise EOFError although the other end `c1` has been closed. Why?

Comment: The pipe you create might be a duplex pipe, but that just means there are (basically) two *non*-duplex pipes in a pair. And like any pipe in the real world each of them is one-way, where data flows from one end to the other. What you write to one pipe must be read from the other end. You can't write to one end of the pipe, and attempt to read it back at the same end. What's written to `c2` must be read from `c1`, and the other way around.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn’t expect receive anything from `c2`. I was expecting an EOFError because the other end `c1` had been closed; however it just blocked at `recv`.

Comment: The problem is that when you create a new process, all the "files" (actual files, pipes, sockets, etc.) are *copied*, with duplicates in the new process. After creating the new process, you will have *two* `c1` pipes (and two `c2` pipes), one in each process. Perhaps you need to close the pipe in *both* processes?